# Swap XML elements using javax.xml.transform.Transformer

Tags: java, xml, transformation, xml-validation

I have following xml portion

```
<xsd:complexType name="xyz">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<Base ...../>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleContent>
<xsd:restriction base="niem-xsd:token">
<xsd:enumeration value="Consumer">
   <xsd:annotation/>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="abc">
   <xsd:annotation/>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:attributeGroup ref="s:SimpleObjectAttributeGroup"/>
```

I have to swap the **enumeration** elements and **attributeGroup** elements as floows

```
<xsd:complexType name="xyz">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<Base ...../>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:simpleContent>
 <xsd:restriction base="niem-xsd:token">
<xsd:attributeGroup ref="s:SimpleObjectAttributeGroup"/>
<xsd:enumeration value="Consumer">
   <xsd:annotation/>
 </xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="abc">
   <xsd:annotation/>
 </xsd:enumeration>
```

. Can I do this using DTD file with **javax.xml.transform.Transformer**. How can I do this ?

Comment: You can do this with a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`, but not with a DTD file. You'll need an XSLT file for that.

Comment: Can you provide me an example XSLT file for this